# knockout.js data on page not updating when updated in modal

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, modal-dialog

I'm using knockout.js and twitter bootstrap's modal plugin to data-bind the user's email address so they can change it via the modal.  However, I'm expecting the see the email address simultaneously update on the page when I'm editing it inside the input box inside the modal.  Is something wrong with my data-binding?

Here's the jsFiddle of the below: http://jsfiddle.net/XN58K/1/

```
var model = {
    "SchoolEmailAddress": "email@domain.com",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "Id": 3
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = new AccountSettingsViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    viewModel.user(model);
});

function User(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}

function AccountSettingsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.user = ko.observable();

    this.editEmail = function() {
        $("#editEmailModal").modal("show");
    }    
}

<div data-bind="with: user">
    <div>Email Address <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $parent.editEmail">Edit</a></div>  
    <div><label data-bind="text: SchoolEmailAddress"></label></div>
</div>    
<div id="editEmailModal" class="modal hide fade" data-bind="with: user">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3><span class="icon-envelope" style="vertical-align: middle"></span> Edit Your Email Address</h3>
        </div>        
        <div class="modal-body">             
            <div class="modalRow"> 
                <div class="modalLabel">Email Address:</div>               
                <div><input type="text" data-bind="value: SchoolEmailAddress" class="span4" /></div>
            </div>                    
        </div>    
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-gray swatch" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-school swatch" data-dismiss="modal">Save Changes</a>        
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a `User` constructor function that is not being used, so none of the user properties are being made observable.

You would want to do something like:

```
viewModel.user(new User(model));
```

This would send the user through the mapping plugin (looks like this was not referenced in the fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/XN58K/2/

That looks like the issue from this question.  It does not get into the Save/Cancel button.